# What character is this man with a gigantic, red-white-black, mace-like weapon cosplaying as in Hyper Japan?

Tags: cosplay

This is a picture of a cosplayer with a red vest(?), black outfit, and a gigantic, red-white-black, mace-like weapon at Hyper Japan 2019. The date 13 Jul

[image: the cosplay photo]

What character is he cosplaying?

Comment: @OP just to clarify (more context means more possible identification), I assume this was taken from the most recent Hyper Japan (July 2019)? Also, if possible ask your friend, what date & time this photo was taken from, because it might be for [one of the Cosplay event timeslot](https://hyperjapan.co.uk/tag/cosplay-photos/)

Comment: Kinda looks like something from God Eater but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for all comments so far. They have been really helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Asking around on Discord, that character is actually not from an anime or manga but rather from a game titled *League of Legends*. It's a skin from one of it's characters named Jayce. Not sure if this would be considered on topic, then. I'll leave it up to those who know better.

Anyway, here's a picture for comparison:
[image]

Credits goes entirely to Discord user 'Untarnished' who identified it.